# How to convert a simple Kotlin Android ListView into Kotlin Multi Platform app?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Hi I am new to Android and Kotlin environment, I am from native iOS background.

I want to create a Kotlin MultiPlatform app and it is run-on both Android and iOS.

For this I created one simple list view like below screen shot.

[image: list view]

**My Source Code:**

**## MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.ktlistviewdemo.srikanth.ktlistviewdemo

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var cityNamesArray  = arrayOf("Melbourne", "Vienna", "Vancouver", "Toronto", "Calgary", "Adelaide", "Perth", "Auckland", "Helsinki", "Hamburg", "Munich", "New York", "Sydney", "Paris", "Cape Town", "Barcelona", "London", "Bangkok")


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var adapterObject = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item,  cityNamesArray)
        var listViewObj: ListView = findViewById(R.id.listview_1)
        listViewObj.adapter = adapterObject
    }
}
```

**## listview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Each List Item is displayed as TextView defined below -->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
    />
```

**## activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It is running on Android Emulator perfectly and then now I want to convert into Kotlin Multi Platform app.

I want to run this app both in Android and iOS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, UI components are not meant to be ported from Android format (XML with native compilation) to other platforms. There is also no determined library which allows you to write UI components and have them translated to the platform-specific languages yet. Kotlin multiplatform is only for business logic, which your UI can call.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
So finally we need to design UI screens separately in their respective native libraries only.

Comment: Yes, until a library comes out which can translate components written in Kotlin to all platforms